# Clear Part of Bitmap to Transparent

Tags: vb.net, picturebox, bitmapimage

I am creating program with multileyered picturebox, the image of picturebox is update dynamically from bitmap in memory, and i want to clear the selected part on bitmap to transparent color so i can see image of picturebox behind it.

Here is my code

```
Dim gBmp As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(GraphLayer(LayerArray))
Dim TileSrcCrop As New Rectangle(nVal(xTile), nVal(yTile), TileSize, TileSize)
Dim TileDrawSize As New Rectangle(nVal(H), nVal(V), TileSize, TileSize)

gBmp.DrawImage(GraphImage(LayerArray), TileDrawSize, TileSrcCrop, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
PicMap(LayerArray).Image = GraphLayer(LayerArray)
```

Thanks

Comment: There's very little guidance to what "selected part" might mean in this snippet.  You'll need to create a new bitmap, draw the bitmap of interest into it then create the hole with Graphics.FillRectangle, using Brushes.Transparent.

Comment: So are the PictureBoxes in the "PicMap" Array literally stacked on top of each other, and you want parts of each PictureBox to be transparent so that you can see the **other** PictureBoxes below?  If yes, then this **cannot** be accomplished by making the images within transparent.  Transparency in .Net is with respect to the container control only.  Thus if you make part of the image transparent it will only display the corresponding color "below" from the parent container; **not** the color(s) of any other control(s) below.  Overlapping controls doesn't work like that in .Net.

Comment: To achieve **overlapping** PictureBoxes with transparency you'd have to literally punch a "hole" in the control by modifying the Region() property.  The parts NOT in the Region() will be clipped allowing controls underneath to be seen.  You can build up the correct parts by using a GraphicsPath() and passing that to the Region() constructor.

Comment: I've been using loop on SetPixel function and set color to transparent and it solved but i think it's little slow if you have any fastest method I would greatly appreciate it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

What I'm about to say may only be for Windows icons, but IIRC, the top left pixel must be assigned the color that you want to designate as the color for transparency. You'll usually see MS use Magenta (255, 0, 255). This is called a transparency mask. Then, anywhere you want the color to be transparent, you use the color you placed in the top left pixel.

HTH -- and let me know if it's only for icons, but I think it's for Windows bitmap files, too.

Comment: Thanks for your reply
I've been using the method MakeTransparent () but I use the alpha channel in the image, so if I use a transparency mask, the image no longer looks semi-transparent

Comment: Ah, I see. Also, I forgot that bitmaps (32-bit ones, that is) support an alpha channel... Hehe, way back in the day, the transparency mask was all we had for Windows bitmaps. :)